# Print blank space in a table with awk

Tags: awk

I have a pattern that looks something like this.

```
 No Type  Pid    Status  Cause Start Rstr  Err Sem Time Program          Cl  User         Action                    Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 DIA    10897 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 1 DIA    10903 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 2 DIA    10909 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 3 DIA    10916 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 4 DIA    10917 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 5 DIA     9061 Wait          yes   no     1   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 6 DIA    10919 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 7 DIA    10920 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 8 UPD    10921 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
 9 BTC    24376 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
10 BTC    25651 Wait          yes   no     1   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
11 BTC    25361 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
12 BTC    15201 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
13 BTC     5241 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
14 BTC    23572 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
15 BTC     8603 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
16 BTC     1418 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
17 BTC    18127 Wait          yes   no     1   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
18 BTC    14780 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
19 BTC    18234 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
20 BTC    14856 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
21 SPO    10934 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
22 UP2    10939 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
```

Now I am using awk to convert it something like below

```
NO=0,Type=DIA,Pid=10897,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
```

above is the sample for one line would be the same for all lines.

we are removing the column header via sed command at runtime, now when we use awk it misses space between status and cause and write the value which should be with start at the cause.

we are using the below command.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS=","}{print "NO="$1,"Type="$2,"Pid="$3,"Status="$4,"Cause="$5,"Start="$6,"Rstr="$7,"Err="$8,"Sem="$9,"Time="$10,"Program="$11,"Cl="$12,"User="$13,"Action="$14,"Table="$15;}'
```

we want the output to be like this

```
NO=0,Type=DIA,Pid=10897,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
```

and one more thing to add these blank fields will have some values from time to time.

Comment: Several questions on your data: **(1)** Is it possible that some columns are not filled while other columns following the empty one are? Example, can you have as output `...,Program=,Cl=foo,...`. **(2)** you mention that the table is whitespace delimited, can you be more specific about this. Are it tabs, spaces, multiple spaces, multiple tabs, a mix, ...? **(3)** Is it possible that some entries actually have spaces?

Comment: Is your initial header and entries aligned? The current example input does not show it like that.

Comment: Furthermore, you mention _Now I am using awk to convert it something like below ..._ but that example is different from the output example you mention later on.

Comment: This is an output of an application, so I don't know

Comment: If you don't know what the data you want to parse looks like, nor why the output is formatted as it is, then you obviously can't write a [robust] tool to parse that input and produce that output so how are we supposed to help you? Good luck!

Comment: From your given input, I can only imagine that you accidentally placed a space too much in front of the first line. If you remove this space, my solution works perfectly.

Comment: @kvantour I will check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i;c=NF;next} NR>2 {for (i=1;i<=c;i++) printf "%s=%s,",a[i],$i;print ""}' file
No=0,Type=DIA,Pid=10897,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=1,Type=DIA,Pid=10903,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=2,Type=DIA,Pid=10909,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=3,Type=DIA,Pid=10916,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=4,Type=DIA,Pid=10917,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=5,Type=DIA,Pid=9061,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=1,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=6,Type=DIA,Pid=10919,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=7,Type=DIA,Pid=10920,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=8,Type=UPD,Pid=10921,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=9,Type=BTC,Pid=24376,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=10,Type=BTC,Pid=25651,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=1,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=11,Type=BTC,Pid=25361,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
No=12,Type=BTC,Pid=15201,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=,
```

NO_ACTION is hard to handle but can be done using fixed file width `FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3"`. But since header are not aligned with data, it may be hard in a simple command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear information on how your data looks like. We do not know if your data is tab-delimited (which would be nice) or only space delimited. If it is space-delimited, as the example gives, than it is hard to distinguish empty columns.

The only way I can see to distinguish empty columns is by assuming that the *header* of the input file, is aligned with the corresponding column, so we can use this to our advantage. The following solution is for GNU awk 4.2 or higher

Have a file `convert.awk` which contains the following content:

```
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
# Read header and find the starting index of each column
# and the corresponding length
# We assume that the headers are uniquely defined.    
(FNR==1) { 
   h[1]=$1; l=1
   for (i=2;i<=NF;++i) { 
       h[i]=$i; t=index($0,$i); f=f " "(t-l); l=t
   }
   n=NF; FIELDWIDTHS = f " *"
   next
}
# skip ruler
/^[-]+$/ { next }
# print record
{
    for (i=1;i<=n;++i) {
        t=(i>NF ? "" : $i); gsub("(^ *| *$)","",t)
        printf "%s%s=%s",(i==1?"":OFS),h[i],t
    }
    printf ORS
}
```

and run with:

```
$ awk -f convert.awk input > output
```

This outputs:

```
No=0,Type=DIA,Pid=10897,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=1,Type=DIA,Pid=10903,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=2,Type=DIA,Pid=10909,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=3,Type=DIA,Pid=10916,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=4,Type=DIA,Pid=10917,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=5,Type=DIA,Pid=9061,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=1,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=6,Type=DIA,Pid=10919,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=7,Type=DIA,Pid=10920,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=8,Type=UPD,Pid=10921,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=9,Type=BTC,Pid=24376,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=10,Type=BTC,Pid=25651,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=1,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=11,Type=BTC,Pid=25361,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=12,Type=BTC,Pid=15201,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=13,Type=BTC,Pid=5241,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=14,Type=BTC,Pid=23572,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=15,Type=BTC,Pid=8603,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=16,Type=BTC,Pid=1418,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=17,Type=BTC,Pid=18127,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=1,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=18,Type=BTC,Pid=14780,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=19,Type=BTC,Pid=18234,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=20,Type=BTC,Pid=14856,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=21,Type=SPO,Pid=10934,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
No=22,Type=UP2,Pid=10939,Status=Wait,Cause=,Start=yes,Rstr=no,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=0,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=NO_ACTION,Table=
```